# FF4 - CSS zindex issue

Tags: css, firefox, z-index

I have a div on the top layer but have controls under this div that users need to be able to click.  It works just fine in IE and FF3 but with ff4 i can not click on controls.  I Can access them with tab.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #ShoppingCart
            {
                z-index:5; 
                position:absolute; 
                text-align:right;
                width:100%;
                max-width:1024px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div>
        <div id="ShoppingCart">
        <input id="SHoppingCartBut" type="submit" value="Shopping Cart" />
<br /> Goes HERE<br /> You Have ITEM COUNT HERE
        </div>
        Choose the Item to order:
        <select id="Select1">
            <option>Item 1</option>
            <option>Item 2</option>
        </select><input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you show your code please.

Comment: Yes, you need to show your code. Ideally, also make a [jsFiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the 'no clicking problem' is actually the CORRECT functionality.

Why not ditch the `witdh: 100%` and use `right:0px`? That works fine for me...

http://jsfiddle.net/tRNJD/

Comment: :)  That did infact solve my problem.  Nothing like overthinking the problem.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With absolute positioning, the element is being removed from the normal flow allowing other elements to rise up and cover the button. That is the problem but that can be handled a number of ways but I don't understand the purpose of using AP at all or the z-index.

Comment: The sample is simplified. The z index is being used so that it appears on top of anything rendered in the  main content div and below the dropdown list menu.  It needs the absolute positioning because floating disrupts the flow of the main content.

Answer (score 0):

Set `pointer-events:none` on the ShoppingCart div to allow clicks to fall through.

Comment: This does not let me click on the Shopping Cart Link inside of the Div.  I know I did not include the link in the example, i just did a quick markup and should have included that.